# How to invoke "Force Quit Applications" on a Mac

Tags: macos, user-interface

Is there a way to programmatically launch the "Force Quit Applications" app that can be launched from the 'Apple menu' or by pressing Command-Option-Esc.

[image]

I haven't been able to find out whether it's a separate app or perhaps something that can be invoked by a command line parameter to Activity Monitor.

I've tried the simulating the keystrokes but it doesn't seem to work:

```
              CGEventFlags flags = kCGEventFlagMaskAlternate | kCGEventFlagMaskCommand;
              CGKeyCode virtualKey = kVK_Escape;

              CGEventSourceRef source = CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStateHIDSystemState);
              CGEventRef KbdEvent = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, virtualKey, YES);
              CGEventSetFlags(KbdEvent, (CGEventFlags)flags);
              CGEventTapLocation location = kCGHIDEventTap;

              CGEventPost(location, KbdEvent);

              CFRelease(KbdEvent);
              CFRelease(source);
```

Answer (score 1):

I also noticed that CGEvents cannot trigger the "Force Quit Applications" window, perhaps it works only on the lower IOHID level (like the Xcode Simulator).

The only way to invoke the window I have found is to use System Events:

```
system("osascript -l JavaScript -e \"Application('System Events').processes['Finder'].menuBars[0].menus['Apple'].menuItems['Force Quit…'].click()\"");
```

You can check to see if the window is open with the following:

```
#include <Carbon/Carbon.h>

int IsForceQuitOpen() {
  int found = 0;
  CFArrayRef windowList = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID);
  CFIndex numWindows = CFArrayGetCount(windowList);

  for (int i = 0; i < (int)numWindows; i++) {
    CFDictionaryRef info = (CFDictionaryRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(windowList, i);
    CFStringRef appName = (CFStringRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(info, kCGWindowOwnerName);

    if (CFEqual(appName, CFSTR("loginwindow"))) {
      found = 1;
    }
  }
  return found;
}
```